# Super large resolution on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, display, resolution, kubuntu, xfce

I am using ubuntu server **10.04** on **Amazon EC2** 64bit.

What I want to do is install a graphical user interface so I can view it using vnc or any other remote desktop, I am currently thinking of kubuntu-desktop or xfce.

But what I want to know is, are there any desktop programs here that I can change the resolution to something like 1280 x 9000.

And, just for those who want to know, I want to do this so that I can open up a browser to full screen then take a huge screenshot of a webpage all in one piece (which is more reliable than plugins because it is in on swoop, and sometimes there are (css position) fixed elements on a web page that follows you).

Thanks.

Comment: Hmmmm, should thits be in askubuntu.com? If so, could you move it there? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It can go to askubuntu.com, but only if you haven't gotten any answers here for a while, if that happens, ask for someone to move it. Don't post again on askubuntu.com, please.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And don't worry, I didn't post on askubuntu :)

Comment: Alright, just wanted to let you know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `vncserver` package included with Ubuntu can be used to create a remote desktop at any size you want.  For instance, to create one at your specified size, you'd run:

```
vncserver -geometry 1280x9000
```

I don't use XFCE, but I just tested KDE with `vncserver` at that resolution and it worked fine.